# jQuery validation on password field not working

Tags: jquery

I am trying to return an error message each the the user leaves the password field blank but it doesn't seem to be working. How do I go about doing this? I am using jQuery validation along with the latest jQuery plugin - having followed the example here: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation.

Here is my code so far: http://jsfiddle.net/k6cvb/.

**HTML**

```
<div id="logo_box"></div>
<form action="#" id="login_form" method="post">
  <div id="login_box">
    <div style="width: 100%;">Department<br />
      <select style="width: 250px; padding-left: 5px;" class="required">
        <option selected="selected">CO</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div style="width: 100%; padding-bottom: 20px; ">Password<br />
      <input id="field" type="password" style="width: 243px;  padding-left: 5px;" class="required"/>
    </div>
    <div style="float: left; padding-top: 6px;"> <a id="forgotpass_link">Forgot your password?</a></div>
    <div style="float:right">
      <input id="login_btn" type="submit" value="Log in"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  </form>
  <div align="center" id="footer">
  </div>​
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    color: #a0a0a0;
    border-top: 3px solid #EAEAEA;

}
#logo_box {
    margin: auto;
    width: 110px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
#login_box {
    width: 250px;
    height: 155px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-top: 1px;
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
    color: #333;
    border: 1px solid #E1D0E8;
}
select, #field {
    border: 1px solid #DDD;
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
#login_btn {
    border: 1px solid #DDD;
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 80px;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;    
    background: #F6F6F6;
    color: #ABABAB;
}

#login_btn:hover {
    border: 1px solid #C06;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;    
    background: #C06 ;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#login_btn:active {
    border: 1px solid #C06;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;    
    background: #fff;
    color: #C06;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#forgotpass_link {
    color: #306;
}

#forgotpass_link:hover {
    color: #C06;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#footer {
    padding-top: 15px;
    font-size: 12px;
}​
```

**JS**

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#login_form").validate();
  });​
```

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you create a method under Login Onclick for validation?? Currently you did $("#login_form").validate().. What will happen by using this method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your input tag has no name attribute... please check..add that and it works

```
input id="field" type="password" style="width: 243px;  padding-left: 5px;" class="required" name="password"/>  // added name filed.. password in this case
```

**Please note that :** 
 
The name attribute is used to reference elements in a JavaScript, or to reference form data after a form is submitted.

**Only form elements with a name attribute will have their values passed when submitting a form.**

try this fiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/k6cvb/16/

CSS

```
label.error { float: none; color: red; padding-left: .5em; vertical-align: top; }
```

Comment: add this to ur css..

label.error { float: none; color: red; padding-left: .5em; vertical-align: top; }
edited the answer.. please check...
if this helped u.. thn please don't forget to accept this as answer.. :) :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("submit buton id").live({
      click : function(e){
          e.preventDefault();

  if($("#login_form").validate()){
       //write code to submit the form
  }else{
       //do whatever you want if the form is not valid
   }
  }
  }); 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of class="required" try using only "required" in input field

```
<input id="field" type="password" style="width: 243px;  padding-left: 5px;" required/>
```

Answer (score 0):

For Jquery plugin validation you have to add `field name` and `class="required"`  for make field required and `minlength="6"` for make input string length minumum 6 necessary.

```
      <input id="field" type="password" style="width: 243px;  padding-left: 5px;" class="required" class="required password"  name="password" minlength="6"/>
```

thanks.